# High-Resolution Content for paint app Using OpenGL ES on iPad device

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, opengl-es

I am working on paint app  [taking reference from GLPaint app] for  iPhone and iPad. In this app I am filling colors in paint-images by drawings lines onscreen based on where the user touches. App working properly for iPhone. In iPad **without zooming** lines on the paint view are proper [no pixel distortion] but **after zooming** lines on the paintView has distorted pixels i.e Content of OpenGL ES is not High Resolution.

I am using Following code for initialize paint view:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
   CGImageRef      brushImage;
   CGContextRef    brushContext;
   GLubyte         *brushData;
   size_t          width, height;
   CGFloat         components[3];

   if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
      CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
      eaglLayer.opaque = NO;
      eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];
      context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

      if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
         return nil;
      }

      if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
      {
         brushImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle 64.png"].CGImage;
      }
      else {
         brushImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flower 128.png"].CGImage;
      }

      // Get the width and height of the image
      width = CGImageGetWidth(brushImage)   ;
      height = CGImageGetHeight(brushImage) ;

      if(brushImage) {
         // Allocate  memory needed for the bitmap context
         brushData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));

         // Use  the bitmatp creation function provided by the Core Graphics framework. 
         brushContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(brushData, width, height, 8, width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(brushImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

         // After you create the context, you can draw the  image to the context.
         CGContextDrawImage(brushContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), brushImage);

         // You don't need the context at this point, so you need to release it to avoid memory leaks.
         CGContextRelease(brushContext);

         // Use OpenGL ES to generate a name for the texture.
         glGenTextures(1, &brushTexture);

         // Bind the texture name. 
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTexture);

         // Set the texture parameters to use a minifying filter and a linear filer (weighted average)
         glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

         // Specify a 2D texture image, providing the a pointer to the image data in memory
         glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, brushData);

         // Release  the image data; it's no longer needed
         free(brushData);
      }

      CGFloat scale;


      if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
      {
         NSLog(@"IPAd");
         self.contentScaleFactor=1.0;
         scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
      }

      else {
         // NSLog(@"IPHone");
         self.contentScaleFactor=2.0;
      }

      //scale = 2.000000;

      // Setup OpenGL states
      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
      CGRect frame = self.bounds;
      NSLog(@"Scale %f", scale);
      glOrthof(0, (frame.size.width) * scale, 0, (frame.size.height) * scale, -1, 1);
      glViewport(0, 0, (frame.size.width) * scale, (frame.size.height) * scale);
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
      glDisable(GL_DITHER);
      glEnable(GL_BLEND);
      glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
      glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      glEnable(GL_BLEND);

      // Set a blending function appropriate for premultiplied alpha pixel data
      glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
      glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
      glTexEnvf(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES, GL_COORD_REPLACE_OES, GL_TRUE);
      glPointSize(width / kBrushScale);

      // Make sure to start with a cleared buffer
      needsErase = YES;

      // Define a starting color 
      HSL2RGB((CGFloat) 0.0 / (CGFloat)kPaletteSize, kSaturation, kLuminosity, &components[0], &components[1], &components[2]);
      [self setBrushColorWithRed:245.0f green:245.0f blue:0.0f];
      boolEraser=NO;
   }

   return self;
}
```

TO CREATE FRAME BUFFER

```
-(BOOL)createFramebuffer {
   // Generate IDs for a framebuffer object and a color renderbuffer
   glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
   glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

   glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
   glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

   // This call associates the storage for the current render buffer with the EAGLDrawable (our CAEAGLLayer)
   // allowing us to draw into a buffer that will later be rendered to screen wherever the layer is (which corresponds with our view).
   [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];
   glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

   // Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
   glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
   glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

   // For this sample, we also need a depth buffer, so we'll create and attach one via another renderbuffer.
   glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
   glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
   glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
   glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);

   if (glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
   {
      NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
      return NO;
   }

   return YES;
}
```

Line Drawn using Following code

```
-(void)renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end {
   static GLfloat*     vertexBuffer = NULL;
   static NSUInteger   vertexMax = 64;
   NSUInteger          vertexCount = 0,
                       count,
                       i;

   [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
   glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

   // Convert locations from Points to Pixels
   //CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
   CGFloat scale;
   scale=self.contentScaleFactor;
   NSLog(@"Scale %f",scale);

   start.x *= scale;
   start.y *= scale;
   end.x *= scale;
   end.y *= scale;

   float dx = end.x - start.x;
   float dy = end.y - start.y;
   float dist = (sqrtf(dx * dx + dy * dy)/ kBrushPixelStep);

   // Allocate vertex array buffer
   if(vertexBuffer == NULL)
      //  vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
      vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
      count = MAX(ceilf(dist), 1);

      //NSLog(@"count %d",count);

      for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
         if (vertexCount == vertexMax) {
            vertexMax = 2 * vertexMax;
            vertexBuffer = realloc(vertexBuffer, vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
            //  NSLog(@"if loop");
         }

         vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (dx) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
         vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (dy) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);

         vertexCount += 1;
      }

   // Render the vertex array
   glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
   glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);
   glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
   [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
}
```

For ipad device content of paint view is proper- high resolution for normal view but after zooming I am not getting High resolution content of paint view pixel of the lines looks distorted.

I have tried to change ContentScaleFactor as well as scale parameter of above code to see the difference but nothing worked as expected. IPad supports contentScaleFactor of 1.0 & 1.5, when I set  contentScaleFactor = 2 Paint view can not display line it shows weird dotted lines.

Is there any way to make contents of OpenGL es high resolution?

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what you mean by high resolution. opengl is a vector library with a bitmap backed rendering system. the backing store will have the size in pixels (multiplied by the content scale factor) of the layer you are using to create the renderbuffer in:

```
- (BOOL)renderbufferStorage:(NSUInteger)target fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)drawable
```

once it is created there is no way to change the resolution, nor would it make sense to do so generally, one renderbuffer pixel per screen pixel makes the most sense.

it is hard to know exactly what problem you are trying to solve without knowing what zooming you are talking about. i assume you have set up a `CAEAGLLayer` in a `UIScrollView`, and you are seeing pixel artifacts. this is inevitable, how else could it work?

if you want your lines to be smooth, you need to implement them using triangle strip meshes with alpha blending at the edges, which will provide antialiasing. instead of zooming the layer itself, you would simply "zoom" the contents by scaling the vertices, but keeping the `CAEAGLLayer` the same size. this would eliminate pixelation and give purdy alpha blended edges.

Comment: you are right, duly edited, although the basic line and point primitives are basically unusable on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **YES**, you can have "High resolution" Content.

But you will have to clearly understand the issue before solving it. This is the long answer :

The brushes you use have a specific size (64 or 128). As soon as your virtual paper (the area in which you draw) will display its pixels larger than 1 screen pixel, you will start to see the "distortion". For example, in your favorite picture viewer, if you open one of your brush and zoom in the picture will also be distorted. You cannot avoid that, unless using vertor-brushes (with is not the scope of this answer and is far more complicated).

The quickest way would be to use more detailled brushes, but it is a fudge as if you zoom enought, the texture will look distorted as well.

You can also add a *magnification filter* using glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_**MAG**_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); . You used MIN in your sample, add this one will smooth the textures

Comment: Hey rockeye, Thanks for replying. In this code I've added paintView in UIScrollview for zooming purpose. Here I am using a brushImage of circular shape after using  GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER it is showing Rectangular shape [I think it is showing rectangle of 64*64 which is the size of brushImage]. I've tried to increse size [128* 128] of brushImage but it only increases size of brushImage on paintview not pixel quality. I have no clue of how to improve brushImage pixel quality so that it won't show distorted content on zoom.

Comment: It is a rather complex question. Quickly, you will have to change your code to differentiate the brush size in your working space (with it's own size and resolution) and the brush resolution. E.g., use a 1024 brush picture and generate mipmaps. In your painter, the user might select a size of the brush tool (related to the working space). If working space res > the brush resolution, it will look fine. Play around with some popular image editor with resolution and brushes and you will find out how to achieve what you want.